# How to set parameters for payShield HSM monitoring tool

Tags: performance, monitoring, hardware-security-module

I am trying to perform an analysis of the data collected using the payShield monitor, a tool for monitoring the hsm Thales payShield 10K.

The tool allows to measure performances, in terms of the % value of total use of the single hsm or the entire group concerned in a time interval.

I have selected "the last 30 days" as analysis interval and the data collected does not seem to make much sense. The manual contains the following information:

" Data is collected each minute; if yuoi choose an interval that is greater than one minutes, there will be multiple points in the interval. The aggregation method determines how to aggregate those values into a single value to display on the chart".

In the "Aggregation method" the options are: Minimum/Average/Maximum value in the interval.
And here the first problems arise:

- When i select Minimum or Average the values obtained are always 0.
- When i select Maximum the values obtained for Saturday and Sunday are always 0.

Important premise: surely the monitored infrastructure is oversized with respect to the real use.

> But how is it that the average value measured over the day is 0? And
> how is possible that the maximum value in the weekend is 0?
> Can someone help me to understand if I’m setting some parameters
> wrong?

Comment: Your questions concern a commercial product characteristics. Have you attempted to direct these questions to the vendor?